# Overload dereference operator in cython

Tags: overloading, cython

In previous code, I receive an object of PPho and I want to retrieve the Pho object inside the shared pointer. How can I do that? I tried to access the shared_ptr directly, but it's private. I tried to dereference it twice. Then I tried to overload the dereference operator, but I was not successful (the error is also shown below).

C++ code (hpp):

```
    class PPho {
      private:
        std::shared_ptr <Pho> PhoPtr;
      public:
        Pho *operator->() const;
        PPho(const PPho &Other);
        PPho(const std::shared_ptr <Pho> &Other);
        PPho(std::nullptr_t);
        PPho();
        PPho &operator=(const PPho &Other);
        PPho &operator=(const std::shared_ptr <Pho> &Other);
        operator std::shared_ptr<Pho>() const;
        operator std::weak_ptr<Pho>() const;
        operator bool() const;
        ///Free the pointed resource and set the Pointer to nullptr.
        void Reset();

    class Pho{
        Pho();
        }
```

Cython header code I'm trying to use (pxd):

```
    cdef cppclass Pho:
        Pho()
        Pho(Pho &Other)        

    cdef cppclass PPho:
        PPho() except +
        shared_ptr[Pho] PhoPtr
        Pho *operator "*operator->()"
```

Cython code (pyx):

```
    cdef class PyPPho:
        cdef PPho* device
        def __cinit__(self):
            self.device = NULL
        cdef assign_device(self, PPho& device_):
            self.device = &device_
        cdef get_pho(self):
            return deref(self.device).get()
```

Error message:

```
    cdef Get(self):
         return deref(self.device).get()
                            ^
     ------------------------------------------------------------

     Ppho.pyx:43:33: Object of type 'PPho' has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: `Pho *operator "*operator->()"` -> `Pho *operator* "operator->()"` ?

Comment: DavidW, if I try your suggestion, it gives me: "Syntax error in C variable declaration".